# Failed to compile spring-native on GraalVM with the message "native-image.cmd returned non-zero result"

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I followed the Spring documentation to try out the Native project, But...

Is it related to the version of GraalVM? What version should I use? Spring officially supports it.

Spring doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-native-build-tools
project: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service

OS and system config:

```
Windows 10 X64 10.0.17763 Build 17763
RAM 28GB
```

JDK:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.1.0 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-22.1-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.1.0 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-22.1-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Maven:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: E:\Appl\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 17.0.3, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-service-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest-service-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Required with Maven Surefire 2.x -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.13</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- Avoid a clash between Spring Boot repackaging and native-maven-plugin -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    
        <repositories>
    <!-- ... -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-release</id>
        <name>Spring release</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- ... -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-release</id>
        <name>Spring release</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Execute command:

```
mvn -Pnative -DskipTests package -X
```

Terminal output:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported OptionOrigin: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\native-image13053469568633812036args
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-30T14:59:03+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.13:build (build-native) on project rest-service-complete: Execution of C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0\bin\native-image.cmd @C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\native-image13053469568633812036args returned non-zero result -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.13:build (build-native) on project rest-service-complete: Execution of C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0\bin\native-image.cmd @C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\native-image13053469568633812036args returned non-zero result
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Execution of C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0\bin\native-image.cmd @C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\native-image13053469568633812036args returned non-zero result
    at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.AbstractNativeMojo.buildImage (AbstractNativeMojo.java:415)
    at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.NativeBuildMojo.execute (NativeBuildMojo.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: mvn -Pnative -DskipTests package -X

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I took care of it, Windows 10 requires an environment configuration:

First you must install "Visual Studio", installer can be found [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com).

It's not necessary to install all options, Anyways, the standard is that you can see the "X64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" tool in the START menu.

- Windows 10 SDK（10.0.19041.0）
- MSVC v143 -VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 生成工具(v14.33-17.3)
- MSVC v143 -VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 Spectre 缓解库(v14.33-17.3)
- 对 v143 生成工具的C++/CLI支持(v14.33-17.3)

Next, Configure environment Variables. Change environments based on your config:

```
MSVC:
D:\DevApp\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629
PATH:
%MSVC%\bin\Hostx64\x64
INCLUDE:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;D:\DevApp\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include;
LIB:
D:\DevApp\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64;
```

Finally you can compile with native-image.
If not, check the GraalVM documentation and try the "*native-image XXXX*" command.

- https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/#from-a-class

Comment: There is nothing to do with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your GraalVM version. As it is stated in the official documentation of GraalVM if you want to use native-image component on Windows, first you need to install Visual Studio and the Visual Studio Build Tools with the SDK related to your Windows version.

[Here](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/docs/getting-started/windows/#prerequisites-for-using-native-image-on-windows) is the link to the native image prerequisites documentation.

And step-by-step instructions for installing Visual Studio and the Visual Studio Build Tools can be found [here](https://medium.com/graalvm/using-graalvm-and-native-image-on-windows-10-9954dc071311), which can be found in the documentation too.

Last but not least native-image tool only works when it is executed from the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt which can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019#developer_command_prompt_shortcuts) as it is stated in the documentation.